# Trying to get this so that the Text will go to the next line under the last line of the table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to put the information below the bottom line in the excel sheet. Here's what I have:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value = "test"
```

However that replaces the current last line with "test" but I need it to be the next line.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "test"
```

Here's the code in my macro

```
Sub SetTestValue()
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "test"
End Sub
```

and here's the output

[image]